# How to bind action to google calendar reminder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, triggers, google-calendar-api, caldav

I'm using ruby on rails:

Using gdata gem.

I'm using Google calendar to save events for my web application.
I also want to receive notifications/reminders for saved events and I noticed that Google calendar notification is to limited to email, SMS and popup and I want to read notifications.

The only clue I have now is to listen to the email sent from @calendar.google.com and trigger actions when email is received.

Is there any other clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is too late to answer your query. I had similar requirements and I see the following options

There is no direct option from google calendar.

I can see two approaches

1) Introduce Timer Script through google script to listen next events for 15 mins and invoke POST of your Application For Further Action
Refer
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_time_triggers
[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getEvents(Date,Date)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#getEvents%28Date,Date%29)

2) Introduce Cron Job Local Server for to pull events in calender,mail through gdata